# How does AWS API Gateway charge users?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

Having read the Pricing docs beforehand, we still not understand the *exact* pricing model of AWS API Gateway ...

We're using REST APIs (`public`), for the `ap-south-1` / Mumbai region. The pricing page says,

[image: pricing snippet]

***'Pay only for the API calls you receive and the amount of data transferred out. There are no data transfer out charges for Private APIs.'***

What does ***'data transfer out'*** mean here? And how would I be charged for it?

---

Any help is appreciated! 
Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 charges:

- The number of requests that you receive.
- Data Transfer Out - The cumulative data size of response body content + headers sent out over the course of a month.

Comment: Thanks @mokugo-devops! :) How could I know which `headers` are being sent to me? And does the size of body content _only_ refers to the total size of all the `attributeNames` & `values` of items being returned to me? Thanks again!

Comment: Hi, this isn't about what is sent to you, its only charged for what you send back to the client. So the total data size of your response

Comment: Oh :D Thanks! But what about the `headers` thing? How should I know how many/which `headers` are being sent to the user? Thanks! [P.S. In my previous post, I meant the 'user' by writing 'me' - sorry for the confusion caused! :) ]

Comment: Hi, headers will be tiny in terms of storage space so fairly negligible. The cost will be more related to the content size.

Comment: Thanks for all your support! :D All my doubts on API Gateway are clear now. Thanks again! :)

Comment: No problem, have a great day :)